# Pass additional arguments to tags$script

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to convert the following HTML to R code using `shiny` tags:

```html
<script data-pace-options='{ "elements": { "selectors": ["#button"] }}' src="pace.min.js"></script>
```

The [tags glossary](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tag-glossary.html) shows that we can embed Javascript into HTML and put it in `tags$script`. However, this doesn't work.

Here's an example that works (without `data-pace-options`):

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny::tags$link(
    href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/0.7.8/themes/black/pace-theme-barber-shop.min.css",
    rel= "stylesheet",
    type= "text/css"
  ),
  tags$script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/0.7.8/pace.min.js")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But putting the `src` argument inside `HTML` doesn't work:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny::tags$link(
    href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/0.7.8/themes/black/pace-theme-barber-shop.min.css",
    rel= "stylesheet",
    type= "text/css"
  ),
  tags$script(HTML('src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/0.7.8/pace.min.js"'))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I reproduce the HTML above with `shiny` tags?

**Edit:** if you want to check if your answer works, use the app below. There shouldn't be a loading bar with `'{"startOnPageLoad" : false}'`, but one should appear if you remove this argument:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny::tags$link(
    href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/0.7.8/themes/black/pace-theme-barber-shop.min.css",
    rel= "stylesheet",
    type= "text/css"
  ),
  tags$script(`data-pace-options` = '{"startOnPageLoad" : false}', src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/0.7.8/pace.min.js")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
tags$script(`data-pace-options` = '{"elements": {"selectors": ["#button"]}}', src = "pace.min.js")
```

When you print it in the R console, you get some escaped characters:

```
<script data-pace-options="{&quot;elements&quot;: {&quot;selectors&quot;: [&quot;#button&quot;]}}" src="pace.min.js"></script>
```

But when you look at the structure with `str`, there's no escaped characters:

```
List of 3
 $ name    : chr "script"
 $ attribs :List of 2
  ..$ data-pace-options: chr "{\"elements\": {\"selectors\": [\"#button\"]}}"
  ..$ src              : chr "pace.min.js"
 $ children: list()
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I've added a small app at the bottom of my post which confirm that the argument `data-pace-options` is not taken into account